# According to DOM, the content between the opening and closing tag of an HTML element is referred to as a property. What is the name of this property?

Tags: javascript

Confused by the wording of this question.
Would it be child, text, innerHTML, or firstchild?
I'm thinking innerHTML, although isn't technically still considered child?
InnerHTML?

Comment: The property that holds all the content is innerHTML. Open your browser inspector and look at the other properties too.

Answer (score -1):

It's an attribute. Basically you are saying that a HTML element and the attributes describes the element to the browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

EDIT: My bad. I wasn't paying attention. Yes, the innerHTML is the answer.